# Single event for any state changes on Form

Tags: c#, events, controls

Is there a possibility to catch `any state changes of controls` (like button press, check box click, edit in text boxes) in a `single` event?

**Background:**

I am programming an education software. The results of the learning steps are shown in a textbox, the `last result` should have a `different colour`.

When the user is `continuing` with the work the colour of the last result should change to the `default colour`.

Is there a possibility to catch `any state changes` of controls (like button press, check box click, edit in text boxes) in a 'single' event so I can reset the colour in the textbox of the last result?

Comment: In WPF that's a task for the ViewModel.

Comment: These are all reported with events.  So of course that's possible.  If you notice that you start writing too many event handlers just to get a line colorized then Application.Idle becomes attractive.

Comment: @HansPassant: So the best way would be for me to implement in the FormShow event a run through all controls and (depending on the kind of the control) add an event to each which fires when the state changes?